# always "using namespace std"?

Tags: c++, string, std

I can understand why we should have this line in a code. That way, you don't have to write std::cout or std::cin, etc.

For std::string though, does the compiler get confused if I include  in a c++ code? For variable str below, is it considered as a cstring type of string or a std::string?

```
include <cstring>
include <string>

using namespace std;

string str;
```

In other words, if I have "using namespace std" at the beginning of the code, is it safe to write all "std::string" simply as "string"? Also If I have "using namespace std", I do not need "using std::string", right?

Comment: It is an `std::string` (assuming you have `#include`.) But `using namespace std;` is a terrible idea in most cases.

Comment: C strings are character arrays or pointers. No conflict at all.

Comment: "you don't have to write std::cout or std::cin, etc." -> actually, you will find that many experts do write their code like this. Code is more often read than written, so you should aim for easy reading, not easy writing.

Comment: The `<cstring>` or `<string.h>` header does not define anything called `string`, so there's no conflict.

Comment: People who write `std::cout` `std::cin` etc are just wrong. It's wrong because it needlessly clutters up the language. Obviously using `using namespace std;` is optimal (and obviously not in a header file)

Comment: @Brandin What's the point of namespaces if you subvert them via `using namespace`?

Comment: @FredOverflow What's the point of namespaces if you have to type `foo::do_something` all the time? With this convention why not just do it the C way and name everything uniquely and just always write `mylib_do_something(...)` for function calls, class names, etc

Comment: @Brandin You only need to qualify with `foo::` if you're crossing namespace boundaries. And personally, I find C++ code with explicit `std::` qualifications a lot more *readable* than without them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "cstring type of string". The `<cstring>` header contains no string class, only functions (and the `size_t` type and the `NULL` macro). In your example, `string` would just be considered `std::string`.

As for `using namespace`. I usually just use it in a very small scope, such as inside of function bodies. Never in header files!

Comment: +1 for "Never in header files!"

Comment: And +1 for not saying "use it in .cpp files, that is absolutely fine..."